# How do I ensure code is generated before compiling when building?

Tags: gradle, antlr

I have a `build.gradle` with the following code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}

ext.antlr = [
    grammarpackage: "org.shirolang.interpreter",
    antlrSource: 'src/main/java/org/shirolang',
    destinationDir: "src/generated/java"
]

sourceSets{
    generated
    main{
        compileClasspath += generated.output
        runtimeClasspath += generated.output
    }
    test{
        compileClasspath += generated.output
        runtimeClasspath += generated.output
    }
}
project.run.classpath += sourceSets.generated.output

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    antlr4
}

sourceSets{
    main{
        java{
            srcDirs 'src/main/java', 'src/antlr/java'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

task antlrOutputDir << {
    mkdir(antlr.destinationDir)
}

task generateGrammarSource(dependsOn: antlrOutputDir, type: JavaExec) {
   // code to generate a antlr grammar
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn generateGrammarSource
    classpath += sourceSets.generated.output
}
```

It outputs:

```
:antlrOutputDir
:compileGeneratedJava UP-TO-DATE
:processGeneratedResources UP-TO-DATE
:generatedClasses UP-TO-DATE
:generateGrammarSource
```

and a whole lot of missing symbol errors because the source code is generated after the `compileGeneratedJava` task is run. Why doesn't adding the `dependsOn` line to the `compileJava` task not force it to be fun first?

If I run `generateGrammarSource` on it's own before `run`, I get now errors, so I know the code generation is working properly.

I tried another [posted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602095/gradle-how-to-generate-source-code-before-compilation-in-android-app) to no avail. I can't seem to inject the task into the proper spot in the build cycle. How do I get `generatedGrammarSource` to run before the compilation steps?

Comment: Problem is in the sourceSets block where I set the srcDirs property. It should be 'src/generated/java' instead of 'src/antlr/java'.

Comment: Jeffrey, if your comment solved your problem, feel free to answer and accept your own question.

Comment: Forgot I could do that. Will accept answer after the 2 day waiting period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `sourceSets` block where I set `srcDirs`. It should be 'src/generated/java' instead of 'src/antlr/java'. The wrong directly was listed causing gradle not to see the generated source.